# Bash get text between two strings with special characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm busy writing a script for Domoticz which can read my Xbox One via gamertag queries. But i require to extract from some special characters. Could not find any solution, i am open to use, GREP, TR, AWK, SED, etc. Preferably one line code.

This is the string:

```
{"type":"XboxOne","titles":[{"id":714681658,"name":"Home","placement":"Background","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:56:33.9199136Z"},{"id":252034287,"activity":{"richPresence":"In Main Menu"},"name":"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition","placement":"Background","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:56:33.9199136Z"},{"id":1693425033,"name":"Spotify Music - for Test","placement":"Full","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:56:33.9199136Z"}]},{"type":"WindowsOneCore","titles":[{"id":328178078,"name":"Xbox App","placement":"Full","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:53:40.7273986Z"}]}]}
```

It's a one line code and i would only require from {"type":"XboxOne till }]}, so that i have only my console information. But these are special characters, i'm  searching high and low but could not find any solution.

This is the string i would end up with.

```
{"type":"XboxOne","titles":[{"id":714681658,"name":"Home","placement":"Background","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:56:33.9199136Z"},{"id":252034287,"activity":{"richPresence":"In Main Menu"},"name":"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim Special Edition","placement":"Background","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:56:33.9199136Z"},{"id":1693425033,"name":"Spotify Music - for Test","placement":"Full","state":"Active","lastModified":"2017-08-26T19:56:33.9199136Z"}]},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly want. The input and output string look the same

Comment: and they're both a mile wide. Can't you boil this down to 10 chars of std data and 2 chars of "special chars"?. (or at least something that doesn't required scrolling right?). This looks like json data. There are tools for processing it available. (not an expert on that, others will probably offer help). Good luck.

Comment: @minhtuannguyen the second string is a substring of the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner

```
cat filename | grep -oP '\{"type":"XboxOne".*?(?=,{"type")'
```

brief explanation:
`(?=,{"type")`: to stop matching once the pattern `,{"type"` is found
`.*?`: to do lazy matching and capture everything until the first match for `,{"type"` (for case if you have multiple objects in your json )

Comment: Of all the posts which where useful this was the one i was looking for. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with an gawk script like this:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { RS="}]}";
        tgt="{\"type\":\"XboxOne"
      }

      { p=index($0, tgt); 
        if(p) printf("%s%s\n\n", substr($0, p ), RS)
      }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`

**Explanation**
The idea is using static strings instead of regexp to minimize escaping the special characters. This is done like this:

- the `RS` record separator is set to the constant string `}]}` each record ends at such a sting, not at line end
- `tgt` is also a constant string used as argument for the `index` function, we only need to escape the double quotes

If the `tgt` is found (i.e. `p>0`), we print the substring from `p` to record end (which is the text up to, but not including the `}]}`) and we additionally print out the `RS`.

You might put the script into a single line argument for `awk` (I have added the necessary `;`), but for sake of clarity I put it into a multiline script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `sed` solution,

```
sed 's/,{"type".*$/,/g' file
```

The command would substitute the string matched the regex `,"type".*$` to `,` which met your request as well.